# Condition class

Tags: c#, ddd

**Up-to-date version**: [Countable and uncountable sets in .NET (IEnumerable and Predicate)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/131971/countable-and-uncountable-sets-in-net-ienumerable-and-predicate).

---

Here is my own predicate class; it is equipped with some operators. Demo:

```
using static BusinessObjects;
using static Console;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteLine(Sell("John Doe", "test@example.com", 10000));
        WriteLine(Sell("John Doe", "test@example.com", 100000));
        WriteLine(Sell("John Doe", "test@example.com", 150000));
    }

    static string Sell(string name, string email, int income)
    {
        if (name == NullOrWhiteSpace || email != ValidEmail)
            throw new Exception("Bad, bad customer.");

        if (income == LowIncome)
            return "Sell car.";

        var middleIncome = !LowIncome && !HighIncome; // magic!!!
        if (income == middleIncome)
            return "Sell home.";

        return "Sell big.";
    }
}
```

Where business definitions are (verbose, verbose C#):

```
static class BusinessObjects
{
    public static readonly Condition<string> NullOrEmpty = 
        new Condition<string>(string.IsNullOrEmpty);
    public static readonly Condition<string> NullOrWhiteSpace = 
        new Condition<string>(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);

    public static readonly Condition<string> ValidEmail = 
        new Condition<string>(new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid);

    public static readonly Condition<int> LowIncome = 
        new Condition<int>(i => i < 30000);
    public static readonly Condition<int> HighIncome = 
        new Condition<int>(i => i > 140000);
}
```

Library class:

```
public class Condition<T>
{
    public Condition(Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        Predicate = predicate;
    }

    Predicate<T> Predicate { get; }

    public static bool operator ==(Condition<T> left, T right) =>
        left.Equals(right);

    public static bool operator ==(T left, Condition<T> right) =>
        right.Equals(left);

    public static bool operator !=(Condition<T> left, T right) =>
        !left.Equals(right);

    public static bool operator !=(T left, Condition<T> right) =>
        !right.Equals(left);

    public static bool operator true(Condition<T> x) => false;            

    public static bool operator false(Condition<T> x) => false;

    public static Condition<T> operator |(Condition<T> left, Condition<T> right) =>
        new Condition<T>(v => left.Equals(v) || right.Equals(v));

    public static Condition<T> operator &(Condition<T> left, Condition<T> right) =>
        new Condition<T>(v => left.Equals(v) && right.Equals(v));

    public static Condition<T> operator !(Condition<T> eq) =>
        new Condition<T>(v => !eq.Equals(v));

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        obj is T && Predicate((T)obj);

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

What do you think? Does this business definitions looks readable and easily reusable?

Comment: Abusing the equality operator in this way is quite objectionable. I'd go with extension methods.

Comment: A little bit of "predicate calculus" - it so easy to combine them now, like that `mediumIncome`.

Answer (score 13):

Honestly I don't see the advantage of `Condition<T>` class over a simpler `Predicate<T>` delegate (eventually with few extension methods to make combinations easier).

Few *issues* that makes me perplex (at best):

- You're abusing `Equals()` to check something that is not equality. This is especially bad because it's absolutely unclear unless users read your `Condition<T>` implementation.
- Equality must be commutative and **transitive** and your actual implementation is not (if `"adriano@example.com" == ValidEmail && "dmitry@example.com" == ValidEmail` however `"adriano@example.com" != "dmitry@example.com"`).
- You're throwing `NotSupportedException` for `GetHashCode()` however it's used by many .NET Framework classes, what if your users will keep your conditions inside an `HashSet`?

In short you're adding a class `Condition<T>` to introduce few *handy* methods (which will be probably never called in real-world) but with a semantic that will confuse everyone will read your code. Think if button to flush toilet was labeled "mirror light". Confusing, right?

Let's go to your *test* code, is this:

```
if (name == NullOrWhiteSpace || email != ValidEmail)
    throw new Exception("Bad, bad customer.");
```

More clear or shorter than this (using C# 6 `using static` syntax):

```
if (IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || !IsValidEMail(email))
    throw new ArgumentException("...");
```

I don't think so and it *integrates* smoothly into existing code. First principle: don't make your users astonished! You still need some syntactic sugar for combinations:

```
public static class PredicateExtensions {
    public static Predicate<T> Not(this Predicate<T> rhs) {
        return x => !rhs(x);
    }

    public static Predicate<T> And(this Predicate<T> lhs, Predicate<T> rhs) {
        return x => lhs(x) && rhs(x);
    }

    public static Predicate<T> Nand(this Predicate<T> lhs, Predicate<T> rhs) {
        return x => !lhs(x) && !rhs(x);
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
var middleIncome = HighIncome.Nand(LowIncome); // No magic!
```

Of course you can drop extension methods if you prefer a plainer syntax:

```
var middleIncome = Nand(HighIncomem, LowIncome); // Even less magic!
```

In general what I feel to suggest is to don't try to abuse C# syntax to make your *business logic* shorter. First of all because shorter code isn't necessarily better (whichever meaning you give to *better*), if you need a simple (or closer to domain) syntax then create a **Domain Specific Language** to describe your business logic at high level.

---

I do not mean that you may not need a `Condition<T>` class at all. If you're modeling your domain specific constraints in C# it can be pretty handy to have a specific class instead of a generic delegate `Predicate<T>` but I wouldn't override the comparison operators, in no way `a == b` can be *a ⊢ b*.

A possible implementation should also introduce a base non-generic `Condition` class to allow combinations - if providing required parameters - for conditions with different `T`s (this is helpful only if your `Condition` class also holds its own data.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41143/discussion-on-answer-by-adriano-repetti-condition-class).