# Countable and uncountable sets in .NET (IEnumerable and Predicate)

Tags: c#, linq, set, ddd

There is a full featured support of countable sets in .NET: `IEnumerable<T>`. What about uncountable sets; sets defined by predicate? How can they be manipulated and interact with `IEnumerable<T>`?

UPDATED: [Countable and uncountable sets](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132005/countable-and-uncountable-sets-in-net-clean-version)

Was: [Condition-class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/131935/condition-class#131941).

Demo (you can play with it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/827DlR) online):

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.String;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var NullOrEmpty = new Set<string>(string.IsNullOrEmpty);
        var NullOrWhiteSpace = new Set<string>(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);
        var WhiteSpace = NullOrWhiteSpace - NullOrEmpty;

        WriteLine(WhiteSpace * " "); // True

        var LowIncome = new Set<int>(i => i < 30000);
        var HighIncome = new Set<int>(i => i > 140000);
        var MiddleIncome = !LowIncome && !HighIncome;

        var salaries = new[] { 25000, 40000, 35000, 80000, 65000, 120000, 200000 };            
        WriteLine(Join(",", salaries - MiddleIncome)); // 25000, 200000
    }
}
```

Where full set of operations is defined as:

```
class Set<T>
{
    public Set(Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        Predicate = predicate;
    }        

    public static bool operator *(Set<T> left, T right) =>
        left.Predicate(right);

    public static bool operator *(T left, Set<T> right) =>
        right.Predicate(left);

    public static Set<T> operator *(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) && right.Predicate(i));

    public static IEnumerable<T> operator *(Set<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right) =>
        right.Where(i => left.Predicate(i));

    public static IEnumerable<T> operator *(IEnumerable<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        left.Where(i => right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator +(Set<T> left, T right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) || right.Equals(i));

    public static Set<T> operator +(T left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Equals(i) || right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator +(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) || right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator +(Set<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) || right.Contains(i));

    public static Set<T> operator +(IEnumerable<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Contains(i) || right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator -(Set<T> left, T right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) && !right.Equals(i));

    public static Set<T> operator -(T left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Equals(i) && !right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator -(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) && !right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator -(Set<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) && !right.Contains(i));

    public static IEnumerable<T> operator -(IEnumerable<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        left.Where(i => !right.Predicate(i));

    public static bool operator true(Set<T> x) => false;

    public static bool operator false(Set<T> x) => false;

    public static Set<T> operator |(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(v => left.Predicate(v) || right.Predicate(v));

    public static Set<T> operator &(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(v => left.Predicate(v) && right.Predicate(v));

    public static Set<T> operator !(Set<T> set) =>
        new Set<T>(i => !set.Predicate(i));

    Predicate<T> Predicate { get; }
}
```

Does this set of operations look mathematically correct?

Comment: This is mind blowing `var WhiteSpace = NullOrWhiteSpace - NullOrEmpty;` :-D null - null = " " LOL magic

Comment: Can you explain your implementations of operators true and false? These don't make any sense to me. Under what circumstances would you want to say `if(set)`?  And why should that always be false?  Also I don't see why you implement union and intersection using *both* the logical and arithmetical operations; can you say why you made this design decision? What does it buy the user, aside from confusion and errors in operator precedence?

Comment: @EricLippert Sorry, I just got it. Some retired garbage survived - here you can find a clean version: [Countable and uncountable sets](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132005/countable-and-uncountable-sets-in-net-clean-version)  _4 specializations on Coursera + Job + codereview = 4 hours of sleep :)_

Answer (score 4):

Interesting try to use C#'s operators for set operations.

However, I think it is not a good extension in productive code because

- you have to learn the meaning of the operators first (and therefore check the implementation because operators are not descriptive).
- compared to methods, it is not possible to add comments to the operators
- the expressions are a little bit confusing to me. For example the '-' operator return different results depending on the position of the operands.

Further more, the functional features of C# provide already similar possibilities. For instance:

```
var salaries = new[] { 25000, 40000, 35000, 80000, 65000, 120000, 200000 };
var isLowIncome = new Func<int, bool>(i => i < 30000);
var isHighIncome = new Func<int, bool>(i => i > 140000);
var isMiddleIncome = new Func<int, bool>(i => !isLowIncome(i) && !isHighIncome(i));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", salaries.Where(s => isLowIncome(s)))); // 25000, 200000
// or
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", salaries.Where(isLowIncome))); // 25000, 200000
```

That is readable and understandable for each C# developer without studing a framework.

Comment: As for me - code reduction is a very good reason to learn something :) All set operations look mathematically correct; `-` is _noncommutative_ by definition. Actually, it is redundant - just a helper.

Answer (score 0):

One more class is probably necessary here:

```
class Intersection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public static readonly Intersection<T> Empty = new Intersection<T>();

    public static implicit operator bool(Intersection<T> intersection) =>
        intersection.Any();

    public Intersection(params T[] enumerable)
    {
        Enumerable = enumerable;
    }

    public Intersection(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        Enumerable = enumerable;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => Enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerable<T> Enumerable { get; }
}
```

So set looks this way now (no changes to the demo Program code above):

```
class Set<T>
{
    public Set(Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        Predicate = predicate;
    }        

    public static Intersection<T> operator *(Set<T> left, T right) =>
        left.Predicate(right) ? new Intersection<T>(right) : Intersection<T>.Empty;

    public static Intersection<T> operator *(T left, Set<T> right) =>
        right.Predicate(left) ? new Intersection<T>(left) : Intersection<T>.Empty;

    public static Set<T> operator *(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) && right.Predicate(i));

    public static Intersection<T> operator *(Set<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right) =>
        new Intersection<T>(right.Where(i => left.Predicate(i)));

    public static Intersection<T> operator *(IEnumerable<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Intersection<T>(left.Where(i => right.Predicate(i)));

    public static Set<T> operator +(Set<T> left, T right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) || right.Equals(i));

    public static Set<T> operator +(T left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Equals(i) || right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator +(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) || right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator +(Set<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) || right.Contains(i));

    public static Set<T> operator +(IEnumerable<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Contains(i) || right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator -(Set<T> left, T right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) && !right.Equals(i));

    public static Set<T> operator -(T left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Equals(i) && !right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator -(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) && !right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator -(Set<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) && !right.Contains(i));

    public static Intersection<T> operator -(IEnumerable<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Intersection<T>(left.Where(i => !right.Predicate(i)));

    public static bool operator true(Set<T> x) => false;

    public static bool operator false(Set<T> x) => false;

    public static Set<T> operator |(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(v => left.Predicate(v) || right.Predicate(v));

    public static Set<T> operator &(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(v => left.Predicate(v) && right.Predicate(v));

    public static Set<T> operator !(Set<T> set) =>
        new Set<T>(i => !set.Predicate(i));

    Predicate<T> Predicate { get; }
}
```