# IEnumerable and Predicate sets in .NET

Tags: c#, iterator, set, ddd

GitHub [Repository](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/Sets)

**Previously**: [Countable and uncountable sets in .NET (clean version)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132134/countable-and-uncountable-sets-in-net-set-operators-demo).

**Thesis**

There is a full featured support of countable sets in .NET: `IEnumerable<T>`. What about uncountable sets; sets defined by predicate? How can they be manipulated and interact with `IEnumerable<T>`?

**Solution**

Let;s introduce two library classes: `Universe` and `Set`, where `Universe` is a factory of `Sets` and `Sets` are defined by predicate, condition like `Func<T, bool>`.

Example:

```
using static Universe; 
Set<int> integers = Set<int>(); 
Set<int> zero = Set<int>(i => i == 0); 
Set<int> positive = Set<int>(i => i > 0);
```

We define some basic calculus on sets:

```
Set<int> nonPositive = !positive;
Set<int> negative = !positive – zero;
Set<int> nonZero = positive | negative;
```

Intersection:

```
Set<int> liquidFreshWaterC = Universe.Set<int>(t => t > 0 && t < 100);
Set<int> liquidSaltWaterC = Universe.Set<int>(t => t >  -21.1 && t < 102);
Set<int> liquidWaterC =  liquidFreshWaterC & liquidSaltWaterC; // = 0 … 100
```

Now, how to test the set (it is just a combined condition underneath, nothing else) – let’s use *intersection* operator, as scalar value is just a set of one element:

```
bool isLiquidWater = liquidWaterC & 25; // = true
```

*Union* operator provides us with an another set:

```
Set<int> temperatures = liquidWaterC | 200; // 0 … 100, 200
```

The most useful feature is an integration with `IEnumerable<T>`.  Let’s have:

```
Int[] tempC = new[] {-100, -10, 0, 10, 100, 200};
```

We can inersect them:

```
Enumerable<int> t = temperatures & tempC; // = 0, 10, 100, 200
```

Please note that non empty `Enumerable<T>` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy); an empty one is falsy:

```
bool nonEmpty = t; // true
```

We can join them, so result will be another `Set<T>`:

```
Set<T> joined = temperatures & tempC; // -100, -10, 0 … 100, 200
```

We can even exclude set from enumeration getting an enumeration, or exclude enumeration from set – getting set as a result.

**Demo**

Let's define `Customer`, `Order`, `Invoice` to calculate discounts (full solution is available [online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3PogEZ) to play with):

```
class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}

class Order
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}

class Invoice
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

Now helpers:

```
static class Balances
{
    public static decimal Invoiced(this Customer customer) =>
        customer.Invoices.Sum(i => i.Total);

    public static decimal Ordered(this Customer customer) =>
        customer.Orders.Sum(o => o.Total);

    public static decimal Balance(this Customer customer) =>
        customer.Ordered() - customer.Invoiced();
}
```

Our discount rules are going to be:

```
 var loyal = Set<Customer>(с => с.Invoiced() > 10000);
 var debtors = Set<Customer>(c => c.Balance() > 0);
 var creditable = Set<Customer>(c => c.Balance() < 5000) & loyal;
 var bulk = Set<Customer>(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.Total > 2000));

 // I think this syntax makes total sense
 var tenOff = bulk & loyal & !debtors;
 var fiveOff = bulk & loyal & creditable - tenOff;
 var noOff = !tenOff & !fiveOff;
```

Let’s test the sets:

```
foreach (var c in Repository.Customers & fiveOff)
    WriteLine($"-5%: {c.Name}");

foreach (var c in Repository.Customers & tenOff)
    WriteLine($"-10%: {c.Name}");

foreach (var c in Repository.Customers & noOff)
    WriteLine($"0%: {c.Name}");
```

**Library** code:

```
static class Universe
{
    public static Set<T> Set<T>() => Set<T>(i => true);
    public static Set<T> Set<T>(Predicate<T> predicate) => new Set<T>(predicate);
}

class Set<T>
{
    public Set(Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        Predicate = predicate;
    }        

    public static Enumerable<T> operator &(Set<T> left, T right) =>
        left.Predicate(right) ? new Enumerable<T>(right) : Enumerable<T>.Empty;

    public static Enumerable<T> operator &(T left, Set<T> right) =>
        right.Predicate(left) ? new Enumerable<T>(left) : Enumerable<T>.Empty;

    public static Set<T> operator &(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) && right.Predicate(i));

    public static Enumerable<T> operator &(Set<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right) =>
        new Enumerable<T>(right.Where(i => left.Predicate(i)));

    public static Enumerable<T> operator &(IEnumerable<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Enumerable<T>(left.Where(i => right.Predicate(i)));

    public static Set<T> operator |(Set<T> left, T right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) || right.Equals(i));

    public static Set<T> operator |(T left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Equals(i) || right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator |(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) || right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator |(Set<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) || right.Contains(i));

    public static Set<T> operator |(IEnumerable<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Contains(i) || right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator -(Set<T> left, T right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) && !right.Equals(i));

    public static Set<T> operator -(T left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Equals(i) && !right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator -(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) && !right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator -(Set<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) && !right.Contains(i));

    public static Enumerable<T> operator -(IEnumerable<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Enumerable<T>(left.Where(i => !right.Predicate(i)));

    public static Set<T> operator !(Set<T> set) =>
        new Set<T>(i => !set.Predicate(i));

    Predicate <T> Predicate { get; }
}

class Enumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public static readonly Enumerable<T> Empty = new Enumerable<T>();
    public static implicit operator bool(Enumerable<T> intersection) => intersection.Any();

    public Enumerable(params T[] items)
    {
        Items = items;
    }

    public Enumerable(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        Items = items;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => Items.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a short summary of the operators and it's operating mode. I am a little bit confused because the same expression `temperatures & tempC;`results in an object of typ `Enumerable<int>` first, and than in an object of type `Set<T>`

Comment: @JanDotNet Here it is, please see below. I have one subtle place in the API. Probably it should be `Enumerable<T>`...

Comment: Even if _syntax_ may seem clear and terse I still have doubts about operator overloading. If you can add _standard_ set operators (with exactly same usage in all cases) then you're welcome but if you reuse existing operators (with different meanings) and you also add corner cases and exceptions then...why??? Please consider how they implemented sets in C++ (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) and discussion about operator overloading (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Comment: Yep, you are right. What do you think about this updated answer below?

Comment: Even if your experiments are considered _controversial_ I like them. I like experimentation in general so from me definetely +1 because they change the point of view to several well _established_ schemas. Thinking outside the box is a good thing ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t Thanks, I think I am starting getting it now. Operators are really something, which supposed to be more traditional semantically then other elements of the program. This is how people think about them. Now it looks more or less solved - all the behavioral properties of operators are preserved. I have also added IEnumerable<T>.Intersect(Set<T>) for compatibility with LINQ :)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks for the links. I think I got it now.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think you're abstracting at the wrong level and the code is confusing to look at. However, as I've made that point before in a previous answer I won't again. Have you at least considered the Specification Pattern? That's a familiar pattern and would seem to give you everything that this does.

Comment: @RobH If an abstraction: 1) precise, 2) concise – then it is adequate. If we could use `|` and `&` on sets of bits in bitmask flags, then we can use on Set of T. Specification pattern is precise, but not concise. Look, everybody knows `foreach` cycle, but it does not hurt to use LINQ with all those tricky callbacks. Let’s agree on disagree.

Comment: So, I'm not really clear on what your goal is here. It's interesting, in a theoretical way, to frame the notion of a predicate in a language closer to set theory, but you don't get any power out of this that you don't get out of familiar patterns. If someone came to me with a programming language that made heavy use of predicate-based sets with operators instead of predicate functions and filters, I'd say 'well that's cool.' But if a developer came to me with production code like this, I'd tell them to rewrite using standard conventions.

Comment: Yep, first of all - it is an experiment - not a production for now. Second, I saw tasks where it can save a lot of efforts on maintaining highly volatile business code in a way which is easy to communicate to the domain expert (no bloating with technical gibberish: s/he can read the code). Third, what would you do to the guy who invented LINQ? :) You could probably say, that it is out of the project scope, etc. - in my case it is about one file, which makes C# business rules readable for non-technical people and less expensive to maintain. Clear win-win situation.

Comment: Hm, looks like an interesting experiment but I do have an issue: What is this notion of countable and uncountable set? [Countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)/[Uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set) have strict defined meaning in mathematics and I don't see what any of your code has to do with it. `collection.Where(predicate)` is perfectly countable (which is all your sets are essentially doing).

Answer (score 1):

**REVISED VERSION**

> GitHub [Repository](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/Sets)

==========================================================================

Previously: [Countable and uncountable sets in .NET (clean version)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132134/countable-and-uncountable-sets-in-net-set-operators-demo).

**Thesis** There is a full featured support of countable sets in .NET: `IEnumerable<T>`. What about uncountable sets; sets defined by predicate? How can they be manipulated and interact with `IEnumerable<T>`?

**What is new?** Operators has been unified:

1) Implicit conversion defined:

- from `IEnumerable<T>` to `Set<T>` => `Set<T>(i => source.Contains(i))`
- from `T value` to `Set<T>` => `Set<T>(i == value)`

2) Operators redefined to ensure symmetry and simplicity:

```
   // tests an element,
   // we can iterate over result or implicitly cast it to Boolean.
   Set<T>[T value] => Enumerable<T> 
   Set<T>[IEnumerable<T> sequence] => Enumerable<T> 

   // Set manipulations
   Set<T> & Set<T> => Set<T>
   Set<T> | Set<T> => Set<T>
   Set<T> - Set<T> => Set<T> // redundant, but so, so useful 
   !Set<T> => Set<T>
```

**Solution** Let’s introduce two library classes: `Universe` and `Set`, where `Universe` is a factory of `Sets` and `Sets` are defined by predicate, condition like `Func<T, bool>`. Example:

```
using static Universe; 
Set<int> integers = Universe.Set<int>(); 
Set<int> zero = Universe.Set<int>(i => i == 0); 
Set<int> positive = Universe.Set<int>(i => i > 0);
```

We define some basic calculus on sets:

```
Set<int> nonPositive = !positive;
Set<int> negative = !positive – zero;
Set<int> nonZero = positive | negative;
```

Intersection:

```
Set<int> liquidFreshWaterC = Universe.Set<int>(t => t > 0 && t < 100);
Set<int> liquidSaltWaterC = Universe.Set<int>(t => t >  -21.1 && t < 102);
Set<int> liquidWaterC =  liquidFreshWaterC & liquidSaltWaterC; // = 0 … 100
```

Now, how to test the set (it is just a combined condition underneath, nothing else) – let’s use *intersection* operator, as scalar value is just a set of one element:

```
bool isLiquidWater = liquidWaterC[25]; // = true
```

Actually, tests return `Enumerable<T>`, which is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy); it could be falsy if empty. We can iterate the result, getting 0 or 1 element.

*Union* operator provides us with an another set:

```
Set<int> temperatures = liquidWaterC | 200; // 0 … 100, 200
```

The most useful feature is an integration with `IEnumerable<T>`.  Let’s have:

```
Int[] tempC = new[] {-100, -10, 0, 10, 100, 200};
```

We can inersect them:

```
Set<int> t = temperatures & tempC; // = 0, 10, 100, 200
```

We can join them, so result will be another `Set<T>`:

```
Set<T> joined = temperatures & tempC; // -100, -10, 0 … 100, 200
```

We can even exclude set from enumeration getting an enumeration, or exclude enumeration from set – getting set as a result.

**Demo** Let’s define `Customer`, `Order`, `Invoice` to calculate discounts (full solution is available [online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3PogEZ) to play with):

```
class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}

class Order
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}

class Invoice
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

Now helpers:

```
static class Balances
{
    public static decimal Invoiced(this Customer customer) =>
        customer.Invoices.Sum(i => i.Total);

    public static decimal Ordered(this Customer customer) =>
        customer.Orders.Sum(o => o.Total);

    public static decimal Balance(this Customer customer) =>
        customer.Ordered() - customer.Invoiced();
}
```

Our discount rules are going to be:

```
 var loyal = Set<Customer>(с => с.Invoiced() > 10000);
 var debtors = Set<Customer>(c => c.Balance() > 0);
 var creditable = Set<Customer>(c => c.Balance() < 5000) & loyal;
 var bulk = Set<Customer>(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.Total > 2000));
 var tenOff = bulk & loyal & !debtors;
 var fiveOff = bulk & loyal & creditable - tenOff;
 var noOff = !tenOff & !fiveOff;
```

Let’s test the sets:

```
   foreach (var c in Repository.Customers.Intersect(fiveOff))
       WriteLine($"-5%: {c.Name}");

   foreach (var c in Repository.Customers.Intersect(tenOff))
       WriteLine($"-10%: {c.Name}");

   foreach (var c in Repository.Customers.Intersect(noOff))
       WriteLine($"0%: {c.Name}");
```

**Library** code:

```
static class Universe
{
    public static Set<T> Set<T>() => Set<T>(i => true);
    public static Set<T> Set<T>(Predicate<T> predicate) => new Set<T>(predicate);
    public static Enumerable<T> Intersect<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Set<T> set) => 
        set[source];
}

class Set<T>
{
    public static implicit operator Set<T>(T value) => 
        new Set<T>(value);

    public Set(params T[] values)
        : this(values.AsEnumerable())
    {
    }

    public Set(IEnumerable<T> values)
        : this(i => values.Contains(i))
    {
    }

    public Set(Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        Predicate = predicate;
    }

    public Enumerable<T> this[T value] =>
        Predicate(value) ? new Enumerable<T>(value) : Enumerable<T>.Empty;

    public Enumerable<T> this[IEnumerable<T> values] =>
        new Enumerable<T>(values.Where(i => Predicate(i)));

    public static Set<T> operator &(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) && right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator &(Set<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right) =>
        left & new Set<T>(right);

    public static Set<T> operator &(IEnumerable<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(left) & right;

    public static Set<T> operator |(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) || right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator |(Set<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right) =>
        left | new Set<T>(right);

    public static Set<T> operator |(IEnumerable<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(left) | right;

    public static Set<T> operator -(Set<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(i => left.Predicate(i) && !right.Predicate(i));

    public static Set<T> operator -(Set<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right) =>
        left - new Set<T>(right);

    public static Set<T> operator -(IEnumerable<T> left, Set<T> right) =>
        new Set<T>(left) - right;

    public static Set<T> operator !(Set<T> set) =>
        new Set<T>(i => !set.Predicate(i));

    Predicate <T> Predicate { get; }
}

class Enumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public static readonly Enumerable<T> Empty = new Enumerable<T>();
    public static implicit operator bool(Enumerable<T> intersection) => intersection.Any();

    public Enumerable(params T[] items)
    {
        Items = items;
    }

    public Enumerable(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        Items = items;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => Items.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }
}
```